# $_POST contains array with string, bind it to variable

Tags: php, arrays, post, var-dump

A var_dump of $_POST gives the following result:

```
array(1) {
    ["postID"]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(2) "76"
        }
}
```

I want to bind the data from position [0] -> "76" to a variable called $id.
What is the correct way to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just access the array element and assign it to your variable.

Comment: `$id = $_POST[0]`? Is that all?

Comment: I tried that @Pharaoh but then I get the error Notice: Undefined offset: 0 and a var_dump of $id would give me NULL

Comment: Oh, I misread the code. It's `$id = $_POST['postID'][0]`. I also indented your code so it's obvious now.

Comment: Thanks @Pharaoh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this value doing:

```
$id = $_POST['postID'][0];
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow up question, If you don't mind.
Is there a way to trim the data stored in the variable so that it only reads 76 instead of string(2) "76"?

Comment: You see `string(2) "76"` because you are doing var_dump, var_dump is explaining you the value is a string of 2 characters which is "76". The actual value is just "76", you can test it doing `echo $_POST['postID'][0];`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Agu Dondo!